# Elasticsearch doc_type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking into the following python

```
documents = es.search(
    body={'query': {'term': {'_uuid': str(_uuid)}}},
    doc_type=self.TYPE,
    index=wildcard_index)
```

How to do `doc_type` in the following curl:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/qb-*/_search?pretty" -d'{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_uuid": "80f8fcee-5d4647b871aa5"
    }
  }
}'
```

Thanks

our elastic search is 2.4.1 version

**UPDATE**

I am looking into our debt codes. there is doc_type in the python codes.
But I cannot find it.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:16683/qb-*/view?pretty"
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "No feature for name [view]"
    } ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "No feature for name [view]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: 2.X is very, very old and no longer supported. please upgrade as a matter of urgency

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `doc_type` in the Elasticsearch url itself, for example: you defined `doc_type` in python request, than your ES URL will be.

```
http://localhost:9200/qb-*/<your-doc-type>/_search?pretty
```

Comment: But I cannot find it.

curl -X GET "localhost:16683/qb-*/view?pretty"
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "No feature for name [view]"
    } ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "No feature for name [view]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}

Comment: @BAE, can your provide the output of `localhost:16683/qb-*/_mappings ?